# Pi Camera V2 vs. Pi NoIR Camera V2

Tags: raspicam

I'm using a **Pi Camera v2**, but the ambient light causes many reflections. So I thought it was necessary to use a **Pi NoIR camera** with infrared led, in this way the cam sees only the part illuminated by the infrared light and with many less reflections. Can it work?
*P.s. sorry for my english*

Comment: What makes you think that infra-red light causes less reflections than visible light?

Comment: Firstly: you calm down. Second: I think that by illuminating an area with infrared LEDs, the camera will only identify the affected area without being disturbed by other colors

Comment: Uhm, good luck getting answers with that attitude.